# Drush dl with dependencies on a multisite environment

Tags: 7, drush, multi-sites

When downloading a project using `drush dl <project>` in a site specific folder on a multisite environment, the module is being downloaded to /modules. However, the dependencies are being downloaded to /sites/all/modules. Is there a way to force Drush to download the dependencies to the site specific module folder using Drush 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope; Drush doesn't pass --destination to the command used to download the dependencies.  The code is in drush_pm_enable_validate; patches welcome.

The issue is at http://drupal.org/node/1632578